# Writing to a CSV file with python - opening it with Excel causes cyrillic letters to not show up properly, what do I do?

Tags: python, excel, csv, cyrillic

I'm using the csv module in Python to write in a CSV file. It has to be like this and it has to also be viewable trough Excel. But when someone views it trough Excel, cyrillic characters show up as all sorts of weird symbols. What kind of encoding must be used exactly when importing in Excel to fix this? I don't have Excel right now and I don't have the option of playing around with Excel on the other guy's computer, so I need to know the proper encoding type in advance. There seem to be a LOT of encoding options in Excel, so it's hard to pick the right one. So...any suggestions?

Comment: Does it look right when opened with a text editor?

Comment: What about calling `.encode('utf-8')` on all strings in rows passed to the `csv` module, and selecting `utf-8` encoding in Excel?

Comment: @kroolik in the encoding list i didnt see utf-8 i saw a few types of cyrillic with large numbers next to them and none of them made it look quite right...

Comment: What's your Excel version?

Comment: the excel version is 2010